# JQuery to change value based on selection in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JQuery I'm trying to create a drop-down menu and then change a certain value on a search input element based on what people select in the menu.

So far I've figured out how to target the value I need to change. I've also gotten as far as having it so that if someone makes **any** selection from the menu, it changes the search input value to one specific value:

```
<div> 
 <form action="setColor" method="post">
   <fieldset>
     <label for="color">Select A Color</label>
       <select name="color" id="color">
           <option>Blue</option>
           <option selected="selected">Red</option>
           <option>Yellow</option>
      </select>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<script> 

  $(function() { 
   $('select[name="color"]').change(function() {
     $('input[name="ancestorId"]').val("9999");
   });
 });

</script>
```

What I need now is something that sets the value according to the menu selection, matched up something like this:

```
Blue = 9999
Red =  8888
Yellow = 7777
```

I'm still looking at examples and will keep trying, but kind of stuck. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you giving your options a value?

Comment: Where are these values going to come from? What does `9999` mean, `8888`? Or are they just a representation?

Comment: Using this as raw material for the menu. http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/   Will values help?

Comment: those are representations for what I want to insert, which are just longer numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the value assignment in the option elements, as they were designed for just that:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="9999">Blue</option>
    <option value="8888" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="7777">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

And the script nearly stays the same, except I've used the elements IDs instead of their names in the selectors (assuming here your ancestor element has such an ID):

```
$(function() { 
    $('#color').change(function() {
         $('#ancestor').val($(this).val());
    }).change(); // Trigger the event
});
```

Note that the chained `.change()` call will trigger the change event that was just assigned, so that the pre-selected item's value will be populated into the text field when the page loads.

See it in action:

```js
$(function() { 
    $('#color').change(function() {
         $('#ancestor').val($(this).val());
    }).change(); // Trigger the event
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="9999">Blue</option>
    <option value="8888" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="7777">Yellow</option>
</select>

<input id="ancestor" type="text" />
```