# Dropdown changing value when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 5 cities (phil, germany, usa, china and russia) and this 5 cities are stored from database and I also have 5 dropdown having those 5 cities as there values.

What i want to happened is this, if the user select germany on dropdown 1, germany value on other dropdowns shouldn't exist anymore. Meaning, germany will be remove automatically on options of the other dropdown.

Can anyone know's how to make this possible on codeigniter?

At the moment i have this initial code http://screencast.com/t/eDTZFhjmon

Is there's a need to use jquery or javascript to make this happened? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having all 5 of the dropdowns generated, and then *disable* all but the first. That way people must answer in *order*.

When the first is selected, run the code, and re-enable the next select and remove the appropriate option from all remaining.

```
<select id="dropone" class="countries">
    <option class=".germany">Germany</germany>
    <option class=".phil">Phil</germany>
    <option class=".usa">USA</germany> 
    <option class=".China">China</germany>
    <option class=".russia">Russia</germany>
</select>
```

I've added classes representing the value in each. Then, use jQuery to hide the selected answer as an option from the **remaining** selects:

```
$('.countries').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class');
    $('.countries:gt('+$(this).index()+')').find('option.'+val).hide();
});
```

Comment: Corrected to remove only from the remaining selects in the row

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you are looking For .Please Follow Some Links :

- 1:[Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)
- 2:[JQuery to change value based on selection in a drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853281/jquery-to-change-value-based-on-selection-in-a-drop-down-menu)
- 3:[How to change DropDownList Selected value in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029276/how-to-change-dropdownlist-selected-value-in-javascript)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example, using just 3 combo boxes. How you want to start will change the js, but this will hide any currently selected option from the other combo boxes.

```js
//hide original
$('select').each(function(){
  var city=$(this).val();
  var cur=$(this).attr('name');
  $('select option[name!='+cur+'][value='+city+']').hide();
});
//when change, hide others
$('select').on('change',function(){
  $('select option').show();
  $('select').each(function(){
    var city=$(this).val();
    var cur=$(this).attr('name');
    $('select option[name!='+cur+'][value='+city+']').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='left half' style='margin-right:10px'>
  <label><strong><span style='color:#F00'>*</span>City Order 1</strong></label>
  <select name='city_order_1' class='select-block mbl cityorder' required>
    <option value='phil' selected>phil</option>
    <option value='china'>china</option>
    <option value='germany'>germany</option>
    <option value='usa'>usa</option>
    <option value='russia'>russia</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class='left half' style='margin-right:10px'>
  <label><strong><span style='color:#F00'>*</span>City Order 2</strong></label>
  <select name='city_order_2' class='select-block mbl cityorder' required>
    <option value='phil'>phil</option>
    <option value='china' selected>china</option>
    <option value='germany'>germany</option>
    <option value='usa'>usa</option>
    <option value='russia'>russia</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class='left half' style='margin-right:10px'>
  <label><strong><span style='color:#F00'>*</span>City Order 3</strong></label>
  <select name='city_order_3' class='select-block mbl cityorder' required>
    <option value='phil'>phil</option>
    <option value='china'>china</option>
    <option value='germany' selected>germany</option>
    <option value='usa'>usa</option>
    <option value='russia'>russia</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I try this one but no luck. Can you please guide me how can i apply this correctly on codeigniter together with my initial code above. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is jQuery free solution.

Sample `HTML` which contains two dropdown with the value as germany, usa, china and russia.

```
<select id="cities0" onchange="upDateValue(this)">
    <option value='china'>China</option>
    <option value='germany' selected>Germany</option>
    <option value='usa'>USA</option>
    <option value='russia'>Russia</option>
</select>
<select id="cities1" onchange="upDateValue(this)">
    <option value='china'>China</option>
    <option value='germany' selected>Germany</option>
    <option value='usa'>USA</option>
    <option value='russia'>Russia</option>
</select>
```

Using `jQuery` to handle your requirement:

```
function upDateValue(v)
{
    var value=v.options[v.selectedIndex].value
    var temp,thisId=v.id;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        temp="cities"+i;
        if (temp!=thisId)
        {
            updateDropDownBox(temp,value);
        }
    }
}

function updateDropDownBox(id,value)
{
    var dropDownBox=document.getElementById(id);
    for (i=0;i<dropDownBox.options.length;i++)
    {
        if (value==dropDownBox.options[i].value)
        {
             dropDownBox.options[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zshc4w9/)